# Why is Garba performed?

Tags: history, tradition

I came to know that in many parts of India [**Garba**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garba_(dance)) is performed.

Is there any secret behind that?

When did the practice of Garba start?

Comment: You should remove word "Science" because that may lead some users to flag your question as off-topic (Science specifications is off-topic here). You can ask question as per scriptures.

Comment: @Rishabh Thank you for your suggestion, I request you to check it again. Is it okay?

Comment: Actually, some users of this site are very hyper (no offense) that they just need a tiny excuse to flag any post. I have seen many user's posts got flags for no reason. Just didn't want that happen to you. That's why I was just advising you to remove this word coz that word might draw attention of those hyper users. As per me, I was fine with your prev. text also.

Comment: what does 'Garba' mean - do you mean Garbhadana samskara ?

Comment: @ram No. OP wants to ask about the "Garba" dance performed during Navaratri festival. - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garba_(dance)